# why I still got an error message 'No JSON object could be decoded' using response.json() while my response.status_code = 200 and json data is valid?

Tags: python, json

The raw `json` data was verified by `json` validator to be valid and the response.status_code = 200, but when I tried to call `json()`, there is value error:

> No `JSON` object could be decoded. It seems I failed to get the response body, because when I print response.content, the result is empty. But I can get the response header using response.header. How comes? I am using requests library, by the way.

How can I solve this problem?
Here is the error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 812, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Hi Kit, can you provide a code example. And can you edit your question to copy your output as text. Screen grabs aren't user friendly to digest for anyone trying to help.

Comment: And show us the body of the response.